# Oracle exp without partitioning

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'd like to know if there is an option in the "exp" command which disables partitioning when exporting an Oracle 11g database. As a matter of fact I'm looking for a simple way to import this data into an Oracle XE database which does not support partitioning. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Data Pump import and export tools, unless you have very specific reasons not to (and with Oracle 11g, I can't think of a reason).

`impdp` and `expdp` have an option for doing exactly what you want: [`partition_options`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL923). Set that to `merge` and partitioned tables will be transformed into non-partitioned ones (during import or export).

See the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL954) to get started with these tools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One thing: am I allowed to use Easy connect syntax for expdp as well ? I'm trying with 
expdp USER/PASSWORD@IPADDRESS:1521/SERVICE PARTITION_OPTIONS=MERGE

But it fails:
LRM-00101: unknown parameter name 'PARTITION_OPTIONS'

Comment: Make sure you're using an 11g version of expdp, that option didn't exist in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look-up the Oracle Database Utilities Guide on more options on how-to use expdp/impdp.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#CIHCAFIG

Note, the PARTITION_OPTIONS parameter can only be used during import.